# Getting a single value from the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is supposed to get a single value from the DB.

What should I consider next? How can I upgrade it?

```
public static String GetConnectionString()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public static String GetProviderName()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ProviderName;
        }

        private Object GetValue(string cmdTxt) 
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdTxt, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    return command.ExecuteScalar() ?? null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    log.Error(string.Format("SELECT User: {0} Base: {3} SQL:{2} Error:{1}", (Session["UserData"] as UserData).id_user, e.Message, cmdTxt, Session["ClientBASE"].ToString()));
                }
                catch { log.Error(string.Format("SELECT User: {0} SQL:{2} Error:{1}", (Session["UserData"] as UserData).id_user, e.Message, cmdTxt)); }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public bool GetValueAsBoolean(string cmdTxt) 
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(this.GetValue(cmdTxt) ?? false);
        }

        public string GetValueAsString(string cmdTxt)
        {
            return (this.GetValue(cmdTxt) ?? String.Empty).ToString();
        }

        public int GetValueAsInt(string cmdTxt)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(this.GetValue(cmdTxt) ?? 0);
        }

        public double GetValueAsDobule(string cmdTxt)
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(this.GetValue(cmdTxt) ?? 0.0);
        }
```

Comment: I note the misspelling in `GetValueAsDobule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static String GetConnectionString()
```

You shouldn't have to use this outside of the class so make it private. Furthermore I would turn it into a property and set it from the static constructor -- that way you avoid having to query your configuration each time you want to make a new call.

This is assuming you don't do it deliberately like this so you can change the connectionstring without halting the application.

---

```
cmdTxt
```

What's that, commandtext? Something more descriptive would be helpful, perhaps just "command"  or "query" would be okay.

---

```
return command.ExecuteScalar() ?? null;
```

"if execution returns null, return null".

Might as well just `return command.ExecuteScalar();`.

---

```
string.Format("SELECT User: {0} Base: {3} SQL:{2} Error:{1}"
```

Keep the indices in ascending order -- it's what everybody expects and you won't have silly mistakes because the arguments passed in expected 0-1-2-3 instead.

---

Why use a try-catch and not a simple `if(Session["ClientBase"] == null)`? Exception handling is expensive and shouldn't be used for normal application flow.

---

```
GetValueAsBoolean
GetValueAsString
GetValueAsInt
GetValueAsDobule
```

I would consider making this a generic `GetValue<T>` and do the conversion inside that method while throwing a `NotSupportedException` for types that you don't want to support. The above idiom smells too much like Java and we're better than that.

Notice also the typo `Dobule`.

Comment: Great feedback, thanks! I definitely use your advices.

But I'd like to explain myself :-)
1. `return command.ExecuteScalar() ?? null;` ExecuteScalar returns `DBNull` not `null`. What is interesting ??-operator treats this as `null` but `Convert` throws InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. This was the most compact sollution what I could think of.
2. `public static String GetConnectionString()` is public because I'm in the middle of refactoring. Earlier value was hardcoded, in many classes. I made method public as first step.

Comment: I was mistaken about `??` handling `DBNull`. It's passed through and have to be explicitly handled.