# Generic getting single value from DB in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics

Few months ago I posted my code [Getting a single value from the DB](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86760/getting-a-single-value-from-the-db). I implemented suggested changes and this is how it looks like right now:

```
public class DataBase : Page
{

    protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    protected static string ConnectionString;

    public DataBase()
    {
        ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
    }

    public static String GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(string query)
        where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
    {
        Object value = GetValue(query);
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
            return GetDefaultValue<T>();
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }

    public static T GetDefaultValue<T>()
        where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
            return (T)(object)String.Empty;
        return default(T);
    }

private static Object GetValue(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogQueryError(query, e);
            return DBNull.Value;
        }
    }

protected static void LogQueryError(string query, Exception e)
    {
        log.Error(string.Format("Error while executing Query ({0}): {1}", query, e.Message));
    }
}
```

One explanation. The purpose of `where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>` is to have single method for value types and strings. (inspired by [C# Generic constraints to include value types AND strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660880/2977131)

What do you think about this piece of code?

Comment: Can I just double check you aren't going to do this: `DataBase.GetValue<int>("select someNumber from dbo.parts where partName = '" + someVariable + "'");`

Comment: @RobH Perhaps the OP should accept a `SqlCommand` object instead?

Comment: This is my plan to pass SQL Command as parameter,  but later. Right now I've a lot of dynamically generated queries. I want to refactor them one by one to SqlCommand and then use polymorphism to get final effect.

Comment: @PiotrNawrot Then perhaps you should look at the suggestion I offered, which allows you to use both at the same time. Once you are ready to make the full transition, you can simply remove the method that takes a `string`.

Comment: @EBrown I'll look for sure. This is what I wanted to do anyway, nevertheless you made a few interesting points. Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Something smells hinky having this class inherit from something called `Page`. Like it's mixing UI and data concerns where it shouldn't. What does `Page` give this class?
2. C# convention is to use language aliases `object` and `string` over the CLR types `Object` and `String`, respectively.
3. Also along the lines of convention, the word is "database", not "data base" and therefore the class should not be named `DataBase`, but rather `Database`.
4. You have two particular dependencies in this class: a connection string and a logger. I'd recommend inverting those dependencies and injecting them into the class at time of construction.
5. Better yet, there are other dependencies, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` being created in the `GetValue` method. These may best be refactored into another class injected into this one.
6. Class member variables should always be `private`. If you need them exposed to the outside, or subclasses, use properties to control access.
7. Use `var` where possible.

So, here's a cut at that:

`IDatabaseAdapter` interface:

```
public interface IDatabaseAdapter
{
    IDbConnection GetConnection();

    IDbCommand GetCommand(IDbConnection connection, string query);
}
```

`DatabaseAdapter` implementation:

```
public class DatabaseAdapter : IDatabaseAdapter
{
    private readonly string _ConnectionString;

    public DatabaseAdapter(string connectionString)
    {
        this._ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString);
    }

    public IDbCommand GetCommand(IDbConnection connection, string query)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection as SqlConnection);

        connection.Open();
        return command;
    }
}
```

`Database` class:

```
public class Database
{
    private readonly ILog _Log;

    private readonly IDatabaseAdapter _DatabaseAdapter;

    public Database(ILog log, IDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter)
    {
        this._Log = log;
        this._DatabaseAdapter = databaseAdapter;
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    protected ILog Log
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Log;
        }
    }

    public T GetValue<T>(string query)
        where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
    {
        var value = this.GetValue(query);

        return Convert.IsDBNull(value) ? GetDefaultValue<T>() : (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }

    public static T GetDefaultValue<T>()
        where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
    {
        return typeof(T) == typeof(string) ? (T)(object)string.Empty : default(T);
    }

    private object GetValue(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = this._DatabaseAdapter.GetConnection())
            using (var command = this._DatabaseAdapter.GetCommand(connection, query))
            {
                return command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.LogQueryError(query, e);
            return DBNull.Value;
        }
    }

    protected void LogQueryError(string query, Exception e)
    {
        this._Log.Error(string.Format("Error while executing Query ({0}): {1}", query, e.Message));
    }
}
```

Sample calling code:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static readonly DataBase _Database = new DataBase(
        LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType),
        new DatabaseAdapter(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString));

    private static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

As a final note, you'll likely want to check for `null` or empty strings in constructors and raise appropriate exceptions then to keep the state of the objects well-known.

Comment: I am so grateful for your review. It showed me how much i didn't notice. 

You get the point, that `Page` didn't give anything to `Database`. I found out that `Database` was inherited by few other classes which needed `Page` and `Database`. Thanks to your question now they inherits directly from `Page` and `Database` is injected or used statically. 

I have a question. Do you think that additional static constructor of `Database` with default `ILog` and `IDatabaseAdapter` is a good idea? It is very convenient to use all this methods as static.

Comment: I have one more question. Why did you make `LogQueryError()` and `GetValue()` non-static?

Comment: No, I do not think having a static constructor with default `ILog` and `IDatabaseAdapter` is a good idea because it causes tight coupling with the implementation, rather than coding to the interface. Also, those methods are now non-static because they rely on instance-specific member data.

Comment: Thanks, I get it.
Another thing - Why do you open connection in `GetCommand()`? Shouldn't connection be opened as late as possible? What is more important if you execute `.Open()` on opened connection you get `InvalidOperationException`. Am I missing sth?

Comment: it's opened in the same place you do in your original code.

Comment: Almost the same, but for methods which accepts SqlCommand as parameter I can't assume that it will have open connection. Hence in this case it's better to open it inside `using` even if opening statement will be repeated in each method...

Comment: I can accept that.

Answer (score 4):

### Usage of String Queries/Mandatory SQL Injection Bits

One of the things I noticed immediately is the use of `string` queries.

This may not be a big deal, but it leaves you open to SQL injection. (I know, mandatory SQL injection statement.) An easy way to fix this would be to rewrite a bit of your code to accept a `SqlCommand` object instead. Perhaps you should optionally allow the user to add a `SqlConnection` to the `SqlCommand` on  their own as well? In a situation like this, I would never actually use the class you have provided as I have no ability to specify my own `SqlConnection` **or** `SqlCommand`.

(Yes, I know you **can** change the `ConnectionString`, but if I want to connect to three different DB's for a set of queries, I would need to create three instances of this `DataBase` class, and then provide a different `ConnectionString` for each. Likewise, if I had fifty queries to run in one batch, I would have to suffer the performance of it opening and closing fifty connections. And that's just unacceptable in my opnion. Just as well, the lack of a `SqlCommand` paramter means I could not provide my own `SqlParameter` list to do parameterized queries, which would mean for me I could never do a `WHERE` clause, as I cannot add parameters.)

You could easily do this with something like the following:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(Command query)
    where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
{
    Object value = GetValue(query);
    if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
        return GetDefaultValue<T>();
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}

public static T GetDefaultValue<T>()
    where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(String))
        return (T)(object)String.Empty;
    return default(T);
}

private static Object GetValue(Command query)
{
    try
    {
        if (query.Connection == null)
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        else
            return command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogQueryError(query, e);
        return DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

This gives you expandability, with the maintainability and SQL injection protection at the client-level. (I assume the users of this class would be quite unhappy if you did nothing to help them protect against SQL injection attacks.)

You could always, for backwards compatibility, leave the `GetValue<T>(string query)` method in, and rewrite it just a tad:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string query)
    where T : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>
{
    Object value;
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query))
        value = GetValue(command);
    if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
        return GetDefaultValue<T>();
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Portability, maintainability, and it's dynamic enough to handle most any situation.

Lastly, for completeness, this would require another rewrite of the `LogQueryError` method:

```
protected static void LogQueryError(SqlCommand query, Exception e)
{
    log.Error(string.Format("Error while executing Query ({0}): {1}", query.CommandText, e.Message));
}
```

### Additional Notes

As Malachi said, other things I would look at changing are the class name (`DataBase` is *awfully* broad), and the `ConnectionString` handling.

If you choose to implement both a method that takes a `SqlCommand`, and a method that takes a `string` (for backwards compatibility), you can remove the method that takes a `string` when you are ready to make a full transition to the `SqlCommand` method.

Comment: You are right that with this class in state as posted `WHERE` statements are possible only when emended with values in query strings. This bad practice, but it was done this way so far. I'm about writing "`SqlCommand` builder" which will allow custom connection strings and passing parameters I only had to come up with the name for it because `SqlCommandBuilder` is already present in the framework :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the entire application to have access to `ConnectionString`? I would think that you want to set how the connection string is changed.  You should probably use a private property with a public get/set so that nothing else inadvertently changes the connection string of your `Database` object in a way you aren't expecting.

`Database` is a little broad for a class that only does a simple query. I think that you could be more specific with this class's name.

Comment: There are other methods in this class for executing queries, getting and setting data but I excluded them from post for clarity. Do you still think this class has too broad name?  Do you have any suggestion of better one?

Comment: I don't know if the Class has too broad of a name, because I don't know what all it does. I don't know who it is, you have hid its personalities from me, I don't know how it will react to being named differently, I don't know how it will react if we change the protected to a private.